# SQL Server : Adding Column Error

Tags: sql-server

I am still finding my feet in SQL Server, and I am trying to do a simple column addition and it is throwing an error. I am trying to add the `KinAdr3` column after the `KinAdr2` column but it is throwing the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'AFTER'.

Below is the SQL statement I am trying to execute

```
ALTER TABLE TBL_MEDICAL_Patient
ADD KinAdr3 nVARCHAR(50) 
AFTER KinAdr2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This might help](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19536/add-a-new-column-and-define-its-position-in-a-table).

Comment: You don't need the "AFTER" clause.. And when modifying a table, you can't add a column in a specific position (*well, not easily*)..

Comment: The error speaks true - there is no `after` in `alter table`. You can only add it to the end

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - He is trying create a new column AFTER a existing column instead of last column

Comment: What if I want to add this column only after a specific column, If I don't put AFTER, will it not put this column at the end, which I don't want...

Comment: @Rahul column order does not matter for storage or querying

Answer (score 4):

The reason is simple as the above syntax is valid in MySQL but is not valid in SQL Server. In SQL Server following syntax is valid:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columnname INT
```

However, a user wanted to add the column between two of the columns. SQL Server is relational engine. The order of the column should not matter in any of the T-SQL operations. It does not matter in most of the cases (except when the table is extra large, and it has many `NULL` columns it impacts the size of the table). In reality whenever user wants to add a column to the table, he/she should just the column and later retrieve the column in a specific order in the table using column names.

It is always a good idea to specify the name of the column in the T-SQL query (using `*` is indeed a bad idea but that is out of scope of this blog post).

For more details please see the [SQL SERVER – How to Add Column at Specific Location in Table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/11/sql-server-how-to-add-column-at-specific-location-in-table/)